# UIWebView + TVOut issues

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

When a video is playing through the uiwebview, i am not getting the UIScreen Notification For TV-Out Cable Plug-in & Plug-Out. The issue is when a video is playing with a TV-Out cable connected, and the user unplug the cable in between the video starts in MPMoviePlayer, i dont want that, instead i want to shuts off the player.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(blockMirroring)name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification
                                                   object:nil]; 
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(blockMirroring) name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
```

Any help???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below solution to solve your problem.

In blockMirroring method, implement below code and may be it helps you.

```
[webview loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```